# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using `Action Mailer` for sending email in the rails app using devise. My `user mailer.rb` file contains this code

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def signup_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email
  end
end
```

But I get this error

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

[image: error screen shot]

Comment: Please share code where you are calling this function?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably something like this. Look at the comment

```
class MailerController < ApplicationController
  def preview
    UserMailer.signup_confirmation # miss the user parameter
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The code which is calling your `UserMailer.signup_confirmation` is apparently not passing the required `user` argument.

You have to fix the calling code to pass the user to the method. You can find the calling code in the stack trace (i.e. either the "Application trace" or "Full Trace" links on the error page as well as in your log.

Comment: I see the trace the data is save in database but email is not sending